# Finding research papers for a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, binary-classification

I found a breast cancer dataset on Kaggle. Here is the link - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/reihanenamdari/breast-cancer

I would like to how could I find out which research papers use this dataset for binary classification.

So far I got only one paper "Breast Cancer Survival Prediction from Imbalanced Dataset with Machine Learning Algorithms" that use this dataset after searching on google scholar.

If there is any technique to find out research papers for a particular dataset, Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super important question.

The reason is that this is not the original source.
If you go to the data -> meta data -> sources, you can see the source is:

`JING TENG, January 18, 2019, "SEER Breast Cancer Data", IEEE Dataport, doi: https://dx.doi.org/10.21227/a9qy-ph35. https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/seer-breast-cancer-data`

Then searching google datasets for the DOI number, we can click through onto the google scholar link to get the following:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22ieee%20dataport%20org%20open%20access%20seer%20breast%20cancer%20data%22